# Protect html/php/image files from tracking

Tags: php, html, image

Is there any way to protect your files(php files/images files) from tracking ?? (TeleportPRO, HTTrack, etc)

-Thanks for your time!

Comment: What do you mean by "tracking" - automated downloading?

Comment: If it's viewable using a browser, it's downloadable. Just don't put your site online if you don't want people to save your data.

Comment: @Pekka, yes, @Capsule I have to put it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTrack crawls through your website then downloads and follows all the links it finds. So anything that a user using a browser will see is what this program will see.

PHP is server side so all the client gets is the html your produce so you do not have to worry about anyone getting your source code with a program like HTTrack. The only way to get your source would be for a attacker to get direct access to the files with ftp/on the system itself...

And as your users will be able to see your images the program will download the images but how would this affect you? If you are selling the images, you could access them through a .php file that checks  if the currently logged-in user has purchased the image and then and only then show it. But for images that are part of your layout/template, it is quite normal for everyone browser etc. to download it. Those programs just download them for local viewing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so if I understand the php files can't be tracked with these programs. Thanks.

Comment: Yes they are only server-side so someone will literally need to gain access to your server to get the files as your web server will/should only output what your .php file output to the user. So relax your Source Code is safe. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think there's some misunderstanding or maybe the question was very dumb. your php SOURCE files can't be downloaded but URLs containing ".php" will be downloaded like any other URL (resulting in HTML code, of course, no PHP code).