# Disable copying data from webpage

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I was looking for any way to create  web page,so that user wont be able to copy content from my web page. i.e. User wont be able to select the any text present on the webpage.
Let's assume i am working on asp.net

Any interesting ideas to accomplish  the task ?

Comment: Have you tried disabling Right-click

Comment: what Dorabubu says, and catch ctrl+c

Comment: But we dont use right click to select text..what if user selects text using mouse and press ctrl +  C?

Comment: no genuine methods every thing can be overidden ;)

Comment: Data present on some of the sites can be unique and if  the author don't want that data to be replicated very easily,in such cases we need some method to block most of the users,assuming most of the user wouldn't be knowing about technical parts such as source code or debugger and without using any over head (such as converting into image,using image server etc)..so we can use any of the techniques answered below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `user-select` CSS3 propertie

HTML like this :

```
<span class="protected">Datas you wants protect</span>
```

And the correspondant CSS :

```
.protected {
    -moz-user-select:none;
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    user-select:none;
}
```

See my example : http://jsfiddle.net/DoubleYo/RPv4q/

This solution is not cross browser but work fine with firefox and chrome/safari

EDIT : advanced user can copy your content with view the page source, make pdf or print your page, and some people mention firebug, fiddler.

Comment: Can we put any transparent DIV in front of the data .so..user can see and read the data but can not copy it ?

Comment: juste add a `<span class="protected">` arround your data you wants to protect and in CSS use the `.protected` selector.

Comment: Please edit your answer and  append your comment in answer...it would be very good if u do so..

Comment: directly coppied without any effort!

Answer (score 18):

Ultimately you can't.

If you disable the ability to select text, the context menu or even just the copy option from the context menu users will still be able to **see** your content.

If they can see it they can copy it:

- Take a screenshot.
- Take a photo.
- Type the text they see into Notepad.
- Dictate the text into a recorder.

It's not worth the development effort and you won't stop the determined copier. All you'll end up doing is annoying your legitimate users.

Add value to your site so people want to keep coming back rather than just taking content and running. This could be:

- Allow user generated content to expand on what's there.
- Update content regularly so it's always fresh.

Comment: Not to mention that any body can capture the page source by using tools such as Fiddler or Firebug!

Comment: We can easily copy text using page source...i did the same when wanted to copy something from a website on which copying was disbaled....but lets talk about a **lay man**...He doesn't know what is page source and debugger :-)

Comment: @Sangram - You can stop right-click etc. see the other answers for the mechanics. However, you have to weigh up the effort involved against the potential benefit. You may find it marginal at best.

Comment: @ Chris F: how about putting  transparent DIV in front of the data .so..user can see & read the data but can not copy it ..how about that ?

Comment: @Samgram - I think I've come across that before - it could work I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

If you send down any text the user will be able to see the source, so disabling copy and paste by any method will not really help stop the determined copier.

The most effective approach would be to render your text in to an image on the server and send down the image and not the raw text, but before you do that there are several downsides to consider: 1) You will require capacity on your server to generate the image. 2) The data load will be higher than just text and compresion will be less effective. 3) You may also loose some caching options.

Is there a particular reason you don't want the user to copy the text, perhaps if you can provide more details other approaches may be possible?

Comment: Sometimes,data present on the site is unique and i don't want this data to be replicated easily.. 
We can easily copy text using page source...i did the same when wanted to copy something from a website on which copying was disabled....but lets talk about a **lay man**..He doesn't know what is page source and debugger :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="<strong class="highlight">javascript</strong>">

 function onKeyDown() {

// current pressed key
 var pressedKey = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();

 if (event.ctrlKey && (pressedKey == "c" || 
                    pressedKey == "v")) {
// <strong class="highlight">disable</strong> key press porcessing
event.returnValue = false;
 }

} // onKeyDown

 </script>
 </head>

 <body>
   <form name="aForm">
    <input type="text" name="aText" onkeydown = "onKeyDown()">
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When someone visits your website they receive the html/css/images/JavaScript that makes up the bulk of your site. So they already have your Content, as most browsers cache this too, to allow quicker browsing.

Read more on HTTP here - http://www.http.header.free.fr/http.html

So it is not quite possible to totally stop anyone that know how the http protocol works. But what you can do is to maybe listen for right clicks and stop normal end users from right clicking and saving a image etc. You can get a snippet here - http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/noright.htm

But if you are talking about protecting images/files that are selling please have a look at [Protect html/php/image files from tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459476/protect-html-php-image-files-from-tracking/5459556#5459556) as it then applies to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your body tag like so:

```
<body onselectstart="return false">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Internet. You can't completely protect the content of the page.

But you can difficult this task for the user.

You can too handle keyboard and mouse inputs, like Ctrl+C or right click of the mouse.

But remember that the user can always see the source code of the page, copy it and paste on a HTML editor.

You can make your site in Silverlight or Flash, but this will "disable" search engines indexing.

Comment: We can easily copy text using page source...i did the same when wanted to copy something from a website on which copying was disabled....but lets talk about a **lay man**...He doesn't know what is page source and debugger :-)

Answer (score 0):

convert your page into a image

Comment: Or force flash. but the referencement will be terrible.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the selection, and with out selection you do not have copy/paste, however I suggest do that only on some parts of your page because is frustrate for the user.

This is the simple code that you can do that, eg, if you have a `div` with `id="notme"`, run the `disableSelOnThis("notme");`

```
    function disableSelOnThis(IdName) {
        var oElem = document.getElementById(IdName);
        if (oElem)
            disableSelection(oElem); }

    function disableSelection(element) {
        element.onselectstart = function() {
            return false;
        };

        element.unselectable = "on";
        element.style.MozUserSelect = "none";
        element.style.cursor = "default";   
    }
```

The code was from : http://ajaxcookbook.org/disable-text-selection/ , but its seams that this site is not longer live.

Of course without javascript enable this is not working and everything ChrisF says still stands.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and Paste the below javascript in your webpage:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
      function disableselect(e) {             
          return false 
      } 
      function reEnable() { 
          return true 
      } 

      document.onselectstart = new Function("return false") 


      if (window.sidebar) { 
          document.onmousedown = disableselect                    // for mozilla           
          document.onclick = reEnable 
      } 

      function clickIE() { 
          if (document.all) { 
              (message); 
              return false; 
          } 
      } 


      document.oncontextmenu = new Function("return false") 

     var element = document.getElementById('tbl'); 

     element.onmousedown = function () { return false; }        // mozilla         

   </script>
```

Note:If the above code not works for Firefox then add style="-moz-user-select:none" in the body tag which needs to be restricted alongwith the above code.