# How to protect content in a webpage to avoid being copied like Codeforces.com?

Tags: php, web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable copying data from webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472223/disable-copying-data-from-webpage)

Most content in a webpage could be copied and pasted in other programs.

How to protect it to avoid being copied?

For example, a kind of coding competition is often held in Codeforces.com. Everyone submits code to solve problems. Besides, they can also choose to hack others' code. To hack means to check the code and find the bug. For fairness, the system was designed to only allow people to see others' code but not be able to copy.

Is there easy way to satisfy this requirement. To convert the code into image is a simple way, but causes too much overhead for the server.

Comment: How much pain are you willing to inflict on your users and how sophisticated is your average user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to do it, despite how much it will annoy people, and might lead to people leaving your site....

You can **replace some reserved words with premade images**, like saying 'echo' is an image of text echo. This will certainly make copying harder. So not changing whole code as image just use premade images, and if so wanted you can even have image-serving-code which sorts out from hashed name which image to use, so that users cannot make scripts to "de-chipher" your text.

So, image would have source "image.php?img=45x1jJEZN99r9xAQhSt5E0" and your image.php sorts out that needs to be use 'echo' image. But also "image.php?img=Nasf1237179sdfx12120" would refer to echo. Use your imagination...

Answer (score 3):

If you send content to someone else's machine, there will always be a way to copy it.  Since the user could access the webpage with an html parser and not even use a browser, whatever tricks browsers give you can always be overridden by advanced users.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the application mechanics so it isn't possible -- require users to finalize a submission (or give up the ability to write one) before they get to look at other users' submissions.